# JHipster with Liquibase in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, jhipster

I'm deploying a JHipster app with the production profile for the first time and i want Liquibase to initialize the database with the correct tables/rows.

However when starting jhipster with the production profile it only results in an exception that say's its unable to connect to MySQL.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:518)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

The error says it unable to connect for user (replaced it with 'myusername' for this post) and that no password is used for the connection. This is where the problem is, a password should be used for the connection but somehow this is not picked up from the configuration. The relevant parts of the configuration:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
        name:
        username: myusername
        password: SuperSecretPassword
        hikari:
            data-source-properties:
                cachePrepStmts: true
                prepStmtCacheSize: 250
                prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
                useServerPrepStmts: true
liquibase:
    contexts: prod
    password: SuperSecretPassword
```

I've added the password to the liquibase.password property myself but that didn't change anything. In other posts the solution was to not set a password for the database user but that is not my preferred option.
Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. Is used ${spring.datasource.password} to reference the database password in the liquibase.password field but that apparently doesn't work.